# How to Diagnose Weatherreport from CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

After building CouchDB from github. I run weatherreport as recommended in documentation to get the following error. How do you diagnose exactly whats going wrong?

```
   17:38:27  WARN:  'escriptize' command does not apply to directory /home/test/workspace/CouchDB-ant_rhel/couchdb
    17:38:27  [ * ] Setup environment ... ok
    17:38:27  [ * ] Ensure CouchDB is built ... ok
    17:38:27  [ * ] Ensure Erlang boot script exists ... ok
    17:38:27  [ * ] Prepare configuration files ... ok
    17:38:27  [ * ] Start node node1 ... ok
    17:38:28  [ * ] Check node at http://127.0.0.1:15984/ ... ok
    17:38:28  [ * ] Running cluster setup ... ok
    17:38:30  [ * ] Exec command bin/weatherreport --etc dev/lib/node1/etc --level error ... ['['node1_diag35200@127.0.0.1'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_memory_use: {'EXIT',{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_float,[[101]],[{error_info,#{module => erl_erts_errors}}]},{weatherreport_util,binary_to_float,1,[{file,[115,114,99,47,119,101,97,116,104,101,114,114,101,112,111,114,116,95,117,116,105,108,46,101,114,108]},{line,80}]},{weatherreport_check_memory_use,check,1,[{file,[115,114,99,47,119,101,97,116,104,101,114,114,101,112,111,114,116,95,99,104,101,99,107,95,109,101,109,111,114,121,95,117,115,101,46,101,114,108]},{line,56}]},{weatherreport_check,check,2,[{file,[115,114,99,47,119,101,97,116,104,101,114,114,101,112,111,114,116,95,99,104,101,99,107,46,101,114,108]},{line,81}]},{weatherreport_runner,'-run/2-fun-0-',2,[{file,[115,114,99,47,119,101,97,116,104,101,114,114,101,112,111,114,116,95,114,117,110,110,101,114,46,101,114,108]},{line,54}]},{erlang,apply,2,[]}]}}
17:38:31  make[1]: *** [Makefile:322: weatherreport-test] Error 1
17:38:31  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/workspace/CouchDB-ant_rhel/couchdb'
17:38:31  make: *** [Makefile:157: check] Error 2
17:38:31  Couchdb built succesfully
```